# hyperledger fabric setup with more than one orderers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

- Preconditions

  - Fabric 1.3
  - I'm trying to use the sample application(Balance Transfer).
  - I can `invoke` for both of orderer.example.com and orderer2.example.com
  - By default, it makes request to `orderer2.example.com` only.
- What I did:

  1. Stop Orderer2.
     `docker stop orderer2.example.com`
  2. Execute `invoke` from SDK
- Expected Behaviour

  - Since orderer2.example.com is stopped, now I expected that the SDK should make request to orderer.example.com for failover.
- Actual Behaviour

  - The SDK makes request to orderer2.example.com only.
  - Error occurs in the SDK.
- The sample yaml file is shown below.

  ```
  channels:
    mychannel:
      orderers:
        - orderer2.example.com
        - orderer.example.com
  ```

Is this behavior correct?
Once one of the orderers is down, doesn't the SDK automatically switch connection to a sound orderer?